# Hyperledger Fabric Multiple hosts fails endorsement : error sending: txid: exists

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm, service-discovery, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm working on Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.6 and node sdk v1.4.8 and trying to configure it on multiple hosts using Docker Swarm and Compose.  My network consist of 2 channels, 3 org and a single raft Orderer. Anchor peers have been successfully updated on channels.

- **Host 1**: channel1 has peer0org1 and peer0org2 + CA-org1 and CA-org2 a Cli and an Orderer
- **Host 2**: channel2 has peer0org1 and peer0org3 + CA-org1 and CA-org3.

My endorsement policy is "**AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')**" for channel1, for channel2 it is "**AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org3MSP.peer')**"

I'm able to successfully build the network and invoke/query transactions via cli but the error starts
when I'm trying to invoke the chaincode via node sdk.

**Node sdk error when trying to invoke using invoke.js**

```
 - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G1:1 - endorsement failed - Error: failed 
    to execute transaction 3b8eb8fe01815c3dd03e1fb840f35a3092974de83694e83a0ec13e548682458d: error sending: txid: 3b8eb8fe01815c3dd03e1fb840f35a3092974de83694e83a0ec13e548682458d(channel1) exists
 - error: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _endorse - endorsement failed::Error: Endorsement has failed
    at DiscoveryEndorsementHandler._endorse (/home/ubuntu/utils/node_modules/fabric-network/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/DiscoveryEndorsementHandler.js:185:19)
```

This error resolves when I use a single org endorsement policy **"AND('Org1MSP.peer')"**.

Additionally, my gateway has discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

**org1 yaml file:**

```
org1peer0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      # couchdb params
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=fabric
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1200s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=800s

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start

    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1
            restart_policy:
              condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.hostname == $WORKER1_HOSTNAME

    ports:
            - published: 7051
              target: 7051
              mode: host
```

Also, the node sdk app is running outside the docker network.

Comment: Do you have gossip enabled and anchor peers set for each organization?

Comment: Hi @GariSingh thanks for a quick reply. Yes the gossip has been enabled and anchor peers have been successfully set for each org. I have added the compose file for org1 as well.